# How to override Constant referenced from inside validates for RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

My model has custom validates like this.

```
class User
  # skip before

  MAX_FILE_SIZE = 10.megabytes.to_i
  validates :file, size: { max: MAX_FILE_SIZE }

  # skip after
end
```

And, I'd like to test about `MAX_FILE_SIZE` by override `MAX_FILE_SIZE` in spec. So, I wrote like this.

```
context "MAX_FILE_SIZE is default" do
  it do
    # test something
  end
end
context "MAX_FILE_SIZE is 1byte" do
  before do
    stub_const "User::MAX_FILE_SIZE", 1.bytes.to_i
  end
  it do
    # test something
  end
end
```

First test was passed. However, second test was failed due to MAX_FILE_SIZE wasn't changed.

Could you tell me why? And how to solve this situation.

Answer (score 6):

The documentation says the constant value resets after the example runs https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-11/docs/stubbing-constants/stub-defined-constant

Did you try stubbing the constant inside the example?

```
context "MAX_FILE_SIZE is 1byte" do
  it do
    stub_const "User::MAX_FILE_SIZE", 1.bytes.to_i
    # test something
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks. Above case will pass. Actually, my spec is request spec by rspec-rails. It seems that constant was changed. But, second example was failed.

Answer (score 1):

I found the reason why.

My custom validator was created only once due to `config.cache_classes = true` in `config/environments/test.rb`. The changed constant value was not effect to the validator's instance.

I couldn't know the best solution.

The following is **not a good** solution.

1. Set `config.cache_classes = false` in `config/environments/test.rb`.
2. Reload model class after set constant value stub, like this.

   ```
   context "MAX_FILE_SIZE is 1byte" do
     before do
       stub_const "User::MAX_FILE_SIZE", 1.bytes.to_i
       load "user.rb"
     end
     it do
       # test something
     end
   end
   ```
3. Forbidden change constant value in model class, like this.

   ```
   class User
     # skip before

     MAX_FILE_SIZE ||= 10.megabytes.to_i
     validates :file, size: { max: MAX_FILE_SIZE }

     # skip after
   end
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You could make a use of lambdas and define the validation like this:

```
class User
  # skip before

  MAX_FILE_SIZE = 10.megabytes.to_i
  validates :file, size: { max: -> { MAX_FILE_SIZE } }

  # skip after
end
```

This way, it should be "reevaluated" properly after you stub the const.